# Running Invoke-Command to Stop-Process while passing a variable not working

Tags: powershell, jenkins, invoke-command

The syntax below absolutely works to stop a process on a remote computer:

```
$hostname = 'PC1'

$process = 'program1*'

$Session = New-PSSession $Hostname

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {param($process) Stop-Process -ProcessName $process -Force} -ArgumentList $process

$Session | Remove-PSSession
```

However, in Jenkins, I parameterized hostname and process, so the user enters the input hostname and process, and Jenkins creates the two variables $env:hostname and $env:process. This is not working well, the argument is not being passed onto Stop-Process:

```
$session = New-PSSession $env:hostname

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {param($env:process) Stop-Process -ProcessName $env:process -Force} -ArgumentList $env:process

$Session | Remove-PSSession
```

The error I'm getting is

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is null.
At C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins10480966582412717483.ps1:25 char:1
+ Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {param($env:process) St ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Stop-Process], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopProcess 
   Command
    + PSComputerName        : pc1
 
Build step 'PowerShell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I know this has something to do with quotes, please give me a hand, thank you!

Comment: Generally, when working with Invoke-Command and Start-Job, I prefer the transfer variables using `Using` instead, i.e. `$Using:Process`

Comment: On what computer is the $ENV:Process set? The one you are running the script from or on the receiving end?

Comment: The same computer the task is running in. The computer takes an input and turns it into $env:variable = userinput. It's parameterized using a program called Jenkins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change anything about your `Invoke-Command` call *except* the input argument, i.e. what you pass to `-ArgumentList`:

```
Invoke-Command `
  -Session $Session `
  -ScriptBlock { param($process) Stop-Process -ProcessName $process -Force } `
  -ArgumentList $env:process
```

Don't ever use an *environment*-variable reference to define a *parameter* variable: <del>`param($env:process)`</del>  In fact, PowerShell should not even *allow* such parameter declarations, but does as of 7.2.x - see [GitHub issue #18401](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18401).

The name of the *parameter* variable, as declared inside the `param(...)` block, is unrelated to whatever *value* you pass to it via `-ArgumentList` (i.e., it is unrelated to what the name of the variable is that you happen to be using to pass that value, and whether that variable is a regular (shell-only) variable or an environment variable), and inside the `-ScriptBlock` argument you must only refer to the value via the *parameter* variable.

See the relevant section of the conceptual [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions#functions-with-parameters) help topic, which, with respect to the `params(...)` method of declaring parameters, applies equally to [script blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`).

---

Note: An **alternative** to passing values *as arguments* to a remotely executing script block, via [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)'s `-ArgumentList` parameter, is to use the **[`$using:` scope](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables) to refer to the values of variables in the *caller's* scope directly in the script block**, as shown in [Dennis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74221280/45375).

In [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), you can apply the `$using:` scope *directly* to an environment-variable reference, which - unfortunately - doesn't work in *Windows PowerShell*, due to a bug:<sup>[1]</sup>

```
# PS 7+ alternative.
# In Windows PowerShell, stick with -ArgumentList or use Dennis'
# approach via an intermediate, regular variable.
Invoke-Command `
  -Session $Session `
  -ScriptBlock { Stop-Process -ProcessName $using:env:process -Force }
```

---

<sup>[1] It works with `Start-Job`, but curiously not with remoting `Invoke-Command` calls.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Or if this makes you feel more at ease...

```
$Session = New-PSSession $env:Hostname
$Process = $ENV:Process

Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {
    Stop-Process -ProcessName $Using:Process -Force 
}
```